# VBA - accessing an element in a string array

Tags: string, vba

I currently have a string array called DayTraArray. I want to assign a particular element in the array to another string. I was wondering if this was the right syntax

```
dim s As String
dim i As Integer

s = DayTraArray(i)
```

Thanks

Comment: `s = DayTraArray(i)` to read the ith entry in the array. To *assign* a new value to it, `DayTraArray(i) = s`

Answer (score 0):

VB arrays may or may not begin at zero. They can have any base. The default base is 1, and can be set to zero with the `Option Base` statement. (Don't do that, you will confuse people - in VB many people will assume the array is 1-based).

To find out the base of an array use the `LBound(arr)` function, which returns the lowest valid index. Find the highest valid index use `UBound(arr)`

To loop through an array properly:

```
Debug.Print "arr has " & (UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) - 1) & " entries"
Debug.Print "    from " & LBound(arr) & " to " & UBound(arr) & "."
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print "arr(" & i & "): " & arr(i)
Next
```

To change the size of an array:

```
Redim Preserve arr(1 To 10)
```